# React Admin customising the filter logic for array query strings

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

On [react-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin) I'm consuming a magento [rest endpoint](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/performing-searches.html) where filter logic is based on arrays.

e.g.

```
GET <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/invoices?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-07-01 00:00:00&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt
```

Apparently react admin's `<Filter />` component doesn't allow complex query strings and just flatten everything down to plain object.

Any ideas about how to hook into this behavior?